# Netflix Eureka and Spring Boot Admin in one application, not showing clients

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-boot-admin

i'm trying to add Spring Boot Admin to my Eureka Server, but it looks like there is something wrong somewhere.

I'm using

```
Spring Boot version 2.1.5.RELEASE (starter parent)
spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server
spring-boot-admin-starter-server
```

My Main Class is annotated with

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableEurekaServer
```

And this is the application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  boot:
    admin:
      context-path: /admin

security:
  basic:
    enabled: false

management:
  security:
    enabled: false

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 15
```

After i started the server, i try to launch a microservice

The application.yaml go the client is the following:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 5
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    lease:
      duration: 5
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  security:
    enabled: false
```

but i see it in eureka as down
[image]

and i cannot see anything in SBA
[image]

Comment: Try to add:
`spring:
   boot:
    admin:
      url:http://localhost:8761` 
to your client `.properties`' file.

Comment: i did it, but no luck, there should be some setting when enabling security that messes all up